# How to manipulate a file's date in order to change its position while sorting a directory in File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

In the Windows 10 File Explorer, I am sorting a directory by date ascending (Right click in the directory > sort by > date / ascending).

I have a file that I created recently, and I would like to modify the date of this file such that I can make it appear to have been created/modified before all the other files in the directory, in order to place it at the top of the directory that is sorted by date ascending.

I have successfully used the following commands in powershell to manipulate the meta data:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "my_file.txt" -Name CreationTime -Value "1/1/2021 0:00:00 AM"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "my_file.txt" -Name LastWriteTime -Value "1/1/2021 0:00:00 AM"
```

I have also confirmed that these commands were successful (by right clicking on the file and going to attributes; both the Created and Modified times were changed).

However, it appears that the File Explorer is not using either of these attributes to "sort by date". My file is still at the very end of the list, even though its CreationTime/LastWriteTime are the earliest of all the files in the directory. I also tried changing the CreationTimeUtc and LastWriteTimeUtc but it did not work.

How can I manipulate a file's date in such a way that Windows File Explorer will respect the date during sorting?

Comment: The default date column in Explorer is date modified. Last access is turned off in modern windows. So add the creation date column to your view and sort by that.

Comment: @user1292580 this worked, thanks! Would you like to make an answer? The attribute was called "date created".

Answer (score 1):

You might refresh the Explorer view by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.
This should re-sort the items.

As additional note, rather than write your own PowerShell solution,
you could use the donation-ware
[Attribute Changer](https://www.petges.lu/)
that can do dates and times and more and sets itself up as a right-click
context menu entry of Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already tried to refresh/open a new window, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I tried the command `Set-ItemProperty .\test.txt -Name LastWriteTime -Value (Get-Date)`. After F5 the list was correctly sorted. Are you sure your date string is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are three times in Windows files. Last Modified, Last Accessed, and Create Time.

By default Last Modified is the one shown.

Last Access in now turned off. In part it makes disk operations a little bit faster. A lot of programs (AV, Indexing, Synching, etc) were accessing files and not resetting the access date making it useless data as it didn't show the user's last access. As it is turned off this makes a great field for custom sorting.

To change the display of which time. In a command prompt use `/t` eg for last access `dir /ta`. In Explorer choose the column of the time you want.

Date created is updated when a file is copied but not when moved.